# Images from api trouble rendering in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using this API to do react rendering but I'm having trouble rendering images with it. Other data from the api can be rendered except for images.  Can anyone can help me with this?

Here is my shortened code (I removed all unnecessary stuff):

```
<strike>
<div>
    {
        post!==null ? post.map(data=>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src={data.image} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <img src={DefaultNotFoundImage} />
                        <div>
                                <h6>{data.artist}</h6>
                                <small>{data.date}</small>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-h" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Likes</h4>
                        <h4>Comments</h4>
                    </div>
                    <h1>{data.title}</h1>
                    <p>{data.description}</p>
                    <p>{data.classification}</p>
                    <p>{data.status}</p>
                    <p>{data.price}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        )
        : <div><h1>No content.</h1></div>
    }
</div>
</strike>
```

The data on `console.log`:

```
image: "uploads\1597059968890Desert.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the whole path like "https://basedir/api/../uploads/..."

If your API and React app running on localhost: https:\localhost..\uploads\1597059968890Desert.jpg`